# Is there an algorithm to factor a many variable polynomial into a sum of squares?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, sums-of-squares, multivariate-polynomial

I have a homogenous degree 8 polynomial in 14 variables. I know it is possible to express it as a sum of 8 squares, but it's a very complicated polynomial and it's infeasible to manipulate it by hand. To be clear, by square I mean a square of a polynomial. I can share the polynomial if it helps. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's always in your best interest to post exactly what you need in detail. In other words of course let's see your polynomial and why you think it's a square. You can't say what someone else might be able to do that might initially look infeasible to you.

Comment: I mean, it has 169 terms, so I doubt anyone will get very far without a computer. I also would have to recalculate it in sage, which is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Oh, I clean forgot about the number of terms. I confess I was thinking only of $n$-nomials for small $n.$

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of properties of polynomials that can be used to obtain this decomposition when possible. There are software tools that help in this purpose such as SOSTOOLS that uses LMI solvers and the properties of Newton polytope to reach this purpose. Check out this [page](http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/).